# Changing Backend Field Display Based on Relationship - OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I am using OctoberCMS along with the Rainlab Builder Plugin to create a plugin for a project of mine.

I have two models, 'Page' and 'Template'. 'Template' has a one-to-many relationship with 'Page'. 'Template' has a boolean property 'Control'.

What I want is to be able to toggle the display of certain field options on Page Form (in the backend) based on the 'Template' Selected.

How do I do the above?

Answer (score 0):

You use [trigger events](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#field-trigger-events).

For example:

```
foo:
    label: Foo
    type: checkbox
    trigger:
        action: show
        field: template
        condition: value[Template Value Here]
```